# How to create a context menu for images with a certain class?

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome-extension, contextmenu

```
chrome.contextMenus.create({
  title : "some title",
  contexts : ["image"],
  type: "normal",
  "onclick":run
});
```

This code calls a context menu for all images. But I need for a certain class of images. Is it possible to do this?
Sorry for my english.